# Splitting a string using a next line regex followed by a digit (JAVA)

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string which I need to split on space, commas, and next line character.
Sample string: "`./homework2 3,phone3,desc3,brand4\n4,phone4,desc4,brand4\n5,phone5,desc5,brand5`"

I am using split function as: `.split("[,\\s+\\n+]");` but I am unable to get the required out put. The program keeps reading `brand4\n4` as one substring.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put + outside `[]` something like: `[,\\s\\n]+`

Comment: I've edited my answer to the output you wanted, if that helps you confirm my answer to the community, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work the way you want:

```
.split(" |,|\\n");
```

This splits the string at a space (" "), a comma, or a next line character. Use the or operator to add more entries if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
           String str = "./homework2 3,phone3,desc3,brand4\\n4,phone4,desc4,brand4\\n5,phone5,desc5,brand5";
           String[] arrOfStr = str.split("[\\s\\n,]+");

           for (String a : arrOfStr) 
                System.out.println(a); 

}
}
```

Out put :

```
./homework2
3
phone3
desc3
brand4\n4
phone4
desc4
brand4\n5
phone5
desc5
brand5
```

**EDIT :**

I found this function in the site : [Link Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-numeric-alphabetic-and-special-symbols-from-a-string/)

```
           for (int i = 0 ; i < arrOfStr.length ; i++) { //YOUR LOOP !!!
               splitString(arrOfStr[i]); 
           }       
}

static void splitString(String str) 
{ 
    StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer(),  
    num = new StringBuffer(), special = new StringBuffer(); 

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) 
    { 
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) 
            num.append(str.charAt(i)); 
        else if(Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))) 
            alpha.append(str.charAt(i)); 
        else
            special.append(str.charAt(i)); 
    } 
    System.out.println(alpha); 
    System.out.println(num);    
} 
}
```

Combine the two functions and you get:

```
homework
2

3
phone
3
desc
3
brandn
44
phone
4
desc
4
brandn
45
phone
5
desc
5
brand
5
```

You can store the values in another array, or whatever you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link to validate regex

https://regex101.com/r/2ZkRBp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using \s+ and \n+ you could use a common quantifier. The below depicts the same

```
String s = "./homework2 3,phone3,desc3,brand4\n4,phone4,desc4,brand4\n5,phone5,desc5,brand5";
String[]s1 = s.split("[,\\s\\n]+");
for(String s2:s1) {
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

As it leads to

```
./homework2
3
phone3
desc3
brand4
4
phone4
desc4
brand4
5
phone5
desc5
brand5
```